# Having Issues Generating Signed Apk

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, dependency-injection, dependencies

I will be as detailed as possible, since I have limited knowledge of Android studio/java.

The issue started when I decided to integrate some admob mediation network network partners which i do with all my apps since my admob account has been limited. I use inmobi, Mopub, Adcolony and MyTarget network for this purpose. Here is a screenshot of how I usually do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z5Lm.jpg)

When i Try to sync Gradle file, I get this error message below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEYpP.jpg)

After trying out different solution the only thing that works is me updation the Firebase Analytic Dependencies below

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'

via Project Structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hID2.jpg)

from 17.3.0  to 19.0.0

Upgrading the dependencies, I was able to sync my project fine.

but I get this error when I try to generate signed APK file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgayS.jpg)

I thought the fault was coming from Mytarget dependencies, so I removed it.  I still got a similar error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVzeC.jpg)

The more dependencies I update, the more errors I get.

Comment: Android Gradle plugin version?

Comment: Android Gradle Plugin Version is 3.5.3

Comment: Update gradle plugin to latest and required gradle version also. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle